# [class*="content"]:before css styles in TwentyThirteen

Tags: css, theme-twenty-thirteen

i found this css style in css stylesheet od TwentyThirteen theme, i search a lot in WP forum and w2schools  and even w3c but i can't find any thing like that.

what that means

Comment: This is a CSS attribute selector and doesn't have anything to do with WordPress.

Comment: See http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a CSS3 Substring matching attribute selector. See section [6.3.2. Substring matching attribute selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-substrings) in the W3C document: [Selectors Level 3](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/).

Quote:

> [att*=val]
>   Represents an element with the att attribute whose value contains at least one instance of the substring "val". If "val" is the empty string then the selector does not represent anything.